# PostGis Polygon into leaflet map using django

Tags: python, leaflet, postgis, geodjango, geos

My issue is that I have no idea how can I visualize a polygon stored in PostGIS into a leaflet map using django.

In the template I'm using this to plot the points :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      function map_init(map, options) {
        {% for each_model in loca %}

          var lon =   {{each_model.location.x}}
          var lat =   {{each_model.location.y}}


          map.setView([lat, lon], 2);

          L.marker([lat, lon]).bindPopup("{{each_model.name}}").addTo(map)

          {% endfor %}
          // get point lat and lon

          // zoom to point & add it to map
        ;
      }

  </script>
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point


class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.PointField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.PolygonField()
```

if I print {{loca.city}} it would print out the GEOS object as follows:

```
SRID=4326;POLYGON ((2.988282590688516 6............))
```

any idea how can I plot the polygons as I'm plotting the points?

UPDATE II :

Printing out what the model producing when using **Shop.object.all()**

```
<QuerySet [<Shop: Shop object (1)>, <Shop: Shop object (2)>, <Shop: Shop object (3)>, <Shop: Shop object (4)>]>
```

the database table looks like this storing polygons and points (x,y)
[image]

I thought about using a query manually (in the view) but it didn't work (cursor.execute("SELECT ST_AsText(city) FROM trial2_shop;)

Using this code :

```
{% for each_model in loca %}

{{each_model.name}} <br>

{% endfor %}
```

the output is this :

```
HELLO 
PARIS 
France 
abc
```

and then using this one :

```
{% for each_model in loca %}

{{each_model.city}} <br>

{% endfor %}
```

the output is this :

```
SRID=4326;POLYGON ((2.988282590688516 6.287501448673132, -2.724608033516236 4.362344411133384, -5.624998658112493 4.800392361058798, -9.316404907598319 4.62520548641869, -7.29492053288002 -2.927082610924476, 8.701173214893267 -0.8189537900473602, 9.667970089758358 3.573231060257538, 5.537110715333732 4.362344411133384, 2.988282590688516 6.287501448673132)) 
SRID=4326;POLYGON ((2.379232127237539 48.99532183070828, 1.835408885125764 48.778601581576, 2.489095408472194 48.61544474629894, 2.780233103744227 48.87985458449839, 2.379232127237539 48.99532183070828)) 
SRID=4326;POLYGON ((4.921880363732911 48.86996904931716, 13.00781786260736 44.28238994198036, -8.08593213445636 32.47943349940858, -25.31249463205829 49.55890707900826, 5.364418038408538e-06 58.4058966101036, -8.789057134358529 49.10068218084409, 4.921880363732911 48.86996904931716)) 
SRID=4326;POLYGON ((10.10742321469805 59.8969527006269, 16.34765758882955 60.31310053764656, 15.02929821401315 57.87662999493084, 12.39257946438035 57.92333496310473, 10.10742321469805 59.8969527006269))
```

so i'm sure what is stored is polygons, but plotting it in the Map template upon retrieval is the issue...

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to use the [leaflet polygon documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#polygon) inside your template.
You will need 2 things for this to work:

1. A list of a [Polygon's coordinates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.coords):

   ```
   lst_coords = [[point.x, point.y] for point in shop_object.city]
   ```

   This will result in a list of lists/pairs of coordinates.
2. Insert the list of coordinates into a leaflet polygon:

   ```
   L.polygon(lst_coords, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
   ```

Now let's apply the above into your example:

1. Add a `property` into your model to return the list of coordinates (that is only for convenience):

   ```
   class Shop(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       location = models.PointField()
       address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       city = models.PolygonField()

       @property
       def city_coords_list(self):
            return [[point.x, point.y] for point in self.city]
   ```
2. Integrate the above into the template:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

     function map_init(map, options) {
       {% for each_model in loca %}

         L.polygon(
           {{ each_model.city_coords_list }}, {color: 'red'}
         ).bindPopup({{ each_model.name }}).addTo(map)

     {% endfor %}
     // Find a way to fit the map accordignly (search the docs)
     ;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @John for this clear explanation, the problem still persists
lst_coords = list(shop_object.city.coords)

This actually returns :
[((2.9882825906885158, 6.287501448673132), (-2.7246080335162364, 4.3623444111333844), (-5.624998658112493, 4.8003923610587975))] 
In which it's not a list of list, i tried these steps, but it didn't actually visualise anything, in leaflet documentatio it's showing : var latlngs = [
    [45.51, -122.68],
    [37.77, -122.43],
    [34.04, -118.2]
]; which is a list of lists, i think if we achieve that the problem is solved

what do you think?

Comment: for example 
Running this : 
  {% for each_model in loca %}

      var coords_list = {{each_model.city_coords_list}};
      alert(coords_list);
      L.polygon(coords_list, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);

      {% endfor %}

the alert would just display this only : 6.287501448673132 
Which is the Y-axis of the first point in the tuble, and that's all

Comment: @kiwis I had tested the coords tuple to list and it worked as I expected it but since you have problems with it, I edited my answer to iterate through the list. Have a look and let me know :)

Comment: would mind sharing your views.py please? 
It still not working for me
    def dd(request):
spost = Shop.objects.all()
    context = {
    'loca' : spost,
    


    }
    return render(request,'def2.html',context)

Comment: @kiwis Can you please explain what "doesn't work" means? Do you get an empty list or something else?

Comment: I actually get an empty leaflet map, in fact i tried to print  "{{city_coords_list}}" but on the front-end it shows ""

Comment: @kiwis Have you checked your data? For example, what `Shop.objects.all()` gives you? Do the instances contained in the `Shop` table have polygons? Can you update your question with some information?

Comment: Hi @John
I update my question, I hope it's enough information. 
The back end is automatically built by django admin to draw polygons... so in the City field it's storing polying

Comment: Any hope?
@john I tried since a week but i don't know what to do anymore :(